# Checking string hash type

Tags: python, hash, md5, sha1, sha256

I am trying to write code which validate if given string is hash in one from following types: md4, sha1, sha256.
My functions right now looks like:

> ```
> def hash_is_md5(_hash) -> bool:
>     search = re.compile(r"([a-fA-F\d]{32})").search
>     return not bool(search(_hash) )
>
> def hash_is_sha1(_hash) -> bool:
>     if len(_hash) != 40:
>         return False
>     try:
>         hash_int = int(_hash, 16)
>     except ValueError:
>         return False
>     return True
>
> def hash_is_sha256(_hash) -> bool:
>     if (len(_hash.encode("utf-8")) / 8) == 32:
>         return True
>     else:
>         return False
> ```

But they doesn't work proper. Any ideas what I coded wrong?

Comment: *"But they doesn't work proper."* isn't a problem statement. Please indicate exactly what is and isn't working; what you're seeing and how it's different from what you expect.

Comment: Also, the only difference between an MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 hash is the length of the hex string. That's it; all other information is gone. So why are you using completely different  methods for each?

Answer (score 0):

The output of sha256 is a hash with 64 characters.  Dividing it by 8 would actually equal 8.  But you don't even need the if statement, you can just check the length of the hash and return that comparison. So the SHA256 function could be

```
def hash_is_sha256(_hash) -> bool:
    return len(_hash) == 64
```

The length for sha1 is 40, and for md5 the length is 32, so their functions look like...

```
def hash_is_sha1(_hash) -> bool:
    return len(_hash) == 40


def hash_is_md5(_hash) -> bool:
    return len(_hash) == 32
```

All of this assumes that you are taking the hexadecimal hash that is the output of each algorithm.  If that assumption is wrong let me know and I can update this.